# How to download dynamically generated multiple pdfs using mpdf at same time AS zip

Tags: php, mpdf

i want to download Zip of the multiple pdf which is dynamically generate using MPDF in php/Codegniter

```
......
$html = $this->load->view('download_inovoice', $finaAr, true);
                    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/../../tmp']);
                    $mpdf->debug = true;
                    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
                    $mpdf->Output('Invoice_' . $order['orderId'] . '.pdf', 'F');
                    
                    $name = 'Invoice_' . $order['orderId'] . '.pdf';
                    $data = $html;
                    $this->zip->add_data($name, $data);
            }
            
           $this->zip->archive('/path/to/directory/my_backup.zip'); 
            $this->zip->download('my_backup.zip');
```

Comment: What is your actual _question_ here? "I want" is not one, and you have not told us anything, what about the code you have shown is not working as intended. Please go read [ask], and then edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(1=1){
$html = $this->load->view('download_inovoice', $finaAr, true);
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/../../tmp']);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$htmlArray[] =  $mpdf->Output('Invoice_' . $order['orderId'] . '.pdf', 'S');
$htmlArrayIds[] =  $order['orderId'];
}
foreach($htmlArray as $key => $file) {
 $data = $file;
 $name = 'Invoice_' . $htmlArrayIds[$key]  . '.pdf';
 $this->zip->add_data($name, $data);
}
$this->zip->download('Invoice_zip.zip');
its working fine
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).